# Authorization Information transmission - Transmission of authorization information (IV) - Patent Application - PRIOR ART REQUEST

Tags: prior-art-request, pre-grant, intellectual-ventures, us20140012609a1

**AN OVERBROAD PATENT ON utilizing a mobile station for the transmission of authorization information in a telecommunication network** - This application from [IV](http://www.intellectualventures.com/) seeks to patent the idea of...A transmitter configured to transmit information to a mobile station, and a processor in communication with the transmitter and configured to generate a verification result indicating a verification status of the transaction, in response to a request received from a verifying device.! 10 minutes of your time can help narrow US patent applications before they become patents.  [Follow @askpatents](https://twitter.com/AskPatents) on twitter to help.

**QUESTION** - Have you seen anything that was **published before 5/2/2000** that discusses:

> - Transmission of authorization information utilizing a mobile station

If so, please submit evidence of prior art as an answer to this question. We welcome multiple answers from the same individual.

**EXTRA CREDIT** - Authorization information may refer to information which can be used to verify a **person's right of admission**, **right to use a service**, etc.

**TITLE: Authorization information transmission using a mobile station**

**Summary**:  [Translated from Legalese into English] A transmitter configured to transmit information to a **mobile station**, the information corresponds to a transaction to be verified, a processor in communication with the transmitter and configured to generate a **verification result** indicating a **verification status** of the transaction, in response to a request received from a **verifying device**, and the **verifying device** is configured to receive information from the **mobile device** and transmit the request to verify the transaction to the **authorization server** based on the information received from the **mobile station**.

- **Publication Number**: [US 20140012609 A1](https://www.google.com/patents/US20140012609)
- **Application Number**: US 14/023,812
- **Assignee**: IV
- **Prior Art Date**: Seeking prior Art **predating** 5/2/2000
- **Open for Challenge at USPTO:** Open through 7/8/2014
- **Link to Google Prior Art Search** - ["Find Prior Art"](https://www.google.com/patents/related/US20140012609#c=0&d1=05%2F02%2F2000)

**Claim 1** requires each and every step below:

> An authorization server comprising:
>
> 1. a transmitter configured to transmit information to a mobile station, wherein the information corresponds to a transaction to be verified; and
> 2. a processor in communication with the transmitter and configured to generate a verification result indicating a verification status of the transaction, in response to a request received from a verifying device, wherein the verifying device is configured to receive information from the mobile device and transmit the request to verify the transaction to the authorization server based on the information received from the mobile station.

In English this means:

> A system comprising:
>
> 1a. A transmitter configured to transmit information to a mobile station,
>
> 1b. The information corresponds to a transaction to be verified;
>
> 2a. A processor in communication with the transmitter and configured to generate a verification result indicating a verification status of the transaction, in response to a request received from a verifying device, and
>
> 2b. The verifying device is configured to receive information from the mobile device and transmit the request to verify the transaction to the authorization server based on the information received from the mobile station.

Good prior art would be evidence of a system that did each and every one of these steps prior to 5/2/2000

You're probably aware of ten pieces of art that meet this criteria already... separately, the applicant is claiming The receiver comprises a wireless communications receiver to receive the information through a wireless connection

---

**"Authorization Information" from the Applicant**

[image]

---

*What is good prior art? Please see our [FAQ](https://patents.stackexchange.com/faq#prior-art).*

*Want to help? Please vote or comment on submissions below. We welcome you to [post your own request for prior art](https://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prior-art-request+pre-grant) on other questionable US Patent Applications.*

---

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of potential prior art for this patent application: [US6223166](https://www.google.com/patents/US6223166?dq=6223166&hl=en&sa=X&ei=XfpDU76aHO3p0QHa94CwDA&ved=0CDUQ6AEwAA)

This patent disclosed a ticket issuing and collection system and method of operation in a distributed information system in which cypher-coded, electronic tickets for an event are issued in hard copy form by a purchaser for authentication at the event by a scanning device.

If you are aware of other potential prior art references, please post it here.